# Search a range and bring back a stacked column of results

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I know this is possible using a combination of probably =FILTER, ARRAYFORMULA and probably QUERY but hopefully, the examples will explain it better than words can.

[image: Testing Data]

Effectively, I have an output (the top table) and I want the formula that will bring back the dates each person has a mismatch (bottom table)

I hope that's clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A2:A10, TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B2:G10="mismatch", B1:G1, )),,999^99)), " "))}, "where Col2 is not null", ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: damn, this is some formulae magic right there. Nice one mate!

Comment: What a hero, i knew it was a combination of them but couldn't for the life of me fathom out which way to use them - superb work very much appreciated